# Plot two columns of a different matrix on the same graph based on a different matrix using cex

Tags: r, plot

I have a question that my title probably hinted at but giving the example will probably be easier. I am working on the lines of codes given by Borcard et al. 2011 with the distribution of fish. There is a matrix of geographical coordinate (x,y) of sites (spa), a matrix of fish species abundance at these sites (spe) and a matrix of environmental factors (env).

One way to represent the fish distribution according to the sites is to use the following code:

```
windows(title="Species Locations", 9, 9)    
par(mfrow=c(2,2))               
plot(spa, asp=1, col="brown", cex=spe$TRU, main="Brown trout", 
xlab="x coordinate (km)", ylab="y coordinate (km)")
lines(spa, col="light blue")
plot(spa, asp=1, col="brown", cex=spe$OMB, main="Grayling", 
xlab="x coordinate (km)", ylab="y coordinate (km)")
lines(spa, col="light blue")
```

etc...

However, this plots 2 different graphs for the OMB and TRU species.
How is it possible to obtain the same graph, but with both the OMB and TRU species on the same graph, still using cex but to get circles of different colors for the two species?

This would help a lot!

Thanks by advance,

Answer (score 0):

I think you want (something like)

```
plot(spa, asp = 1, type = "n", main = "Brown trout", 
     xlab = "x coordinate (km)", ylab = "y coordinate (km)")
lines(spa, col="light blue")
points(spa, col = "brown", cex = spe$TRU)
points(spa, col = "green", cex = spe$OMB)
legend("topright", legend = c("Brown Trout", "Grayling"),
       col = c("brown","green"), pch = 1, bty = "n")
```

The main idea here is to just add the data points sequentially with `points()` calls, just as `lines()` was used to add lines to each plot after the data were drawn (note here I draw them in the background to avoid overplotting the data).

There is one clear issue with what you want to do however; the two `points()` calls are essentially plotting data in the same locations on the plot and hence you may run into issues with one set of data overplotting the one for the other species.

If you want to have many species (not just two) on the same figure (multiple plots like their example), then I would suggest switching to **lattice** or **ggplot2** to do the plotting, but you'd need to massage the data a bit first. If you care to update your question with the code needed to get the data for Borcard *et al*'s example then I will update my answer with such an example. I feel this would be a better way of showing this data than overlaying two or more species on the same real estate.

Comment: Thank you for your input Gavin! In fact, this is a question from one of my students in a bio class. I agree with you that having many species on the same plot may not be the most ideal thing to do. In fact, what is given by Brocard et al. seems very appropriate to me, but as they have to write a report on their own, I would rather have them experimenting different ways of showing the data.